# make a form that cannot be closed

Tags: winforms

How can i make a form so that it can never be closed by pressing the "X" button ?

Comment: Don't, or you and all your descendants will be cursed by each and every user.

Comment: :))) it's a must in my app, it's nothing that i was looking forward to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook the form's Closing event, like this:

```
myForm.Closing += MyForm_Closing;

public void MyForm_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: This event really exists to provide a cancellation point in the close process.  It's the right place to put "Are you sure you want to quit?" prompts.
To get rid of the X button altogether, just do `myForm.ControlBox = false;`.

Answer (score 1):

Use with caution, deviating from expectation is often a bad idea.

You need to handle the onclosing event

```
Form1_OnClosing(sender blah, eventarg e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Can't remember the exact syntax 100%